# Docker redirect automatically from port 8000 to 8080 - Docker Bug

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, hyper-v

I've a problem with my Docker.
I use `Docker Desktop version 20.10.2, build 2291f61` and `docker-compose version 1.27.4, build 40524192` on `Windows 10 Pro`.

Since a few hours, when I launch any docker-compose and I'm going on my browser to contact `localhost:8000`, I'm automatically redirect to `localhost:8080`.

I've delete all my Docker data (images, containers, networks...), I've also reset Docker to factory defaults but that didn't solve anything... I don't know what is going on !

Here, an example of one of my docker-compose.yml :

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:php7.4-fpm
    container_name: e2i-scollado-cours-wordpress
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
    volumes:
      - ./storage/wordpress:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - e2i-scollado-cours

  db:
    image: mariadb:10.5
    container_name: e2i-scollado-cours-database
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - ./storage/database:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - e2i-scollado-cours

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    container_name: e2i-scollado-cours-phpmyadmin
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
      - PMA_HOSTS=database
      - PMA_USER=wordpress
      - PMA_PASSWORD=password
    networks:
      - e2i-scollado-cours

networks:
  e2i-scollado-cours:
    driver: 
      bridge
```

```sh
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                            NAMES
2e6c54623675   wordpress:php7.4-fpm   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   17 minutes ago   Up 17 minutes   9000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp   e2i-scollado-cours-wordpress
bbfb12fa4c14   mariadb:10.5           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   17 minutes ago   Up 17 minutes   0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp           e2i-scollado-cours-database
243fc759179c   phpmyadmin             "/docker-entrypoint.…"   17 minutes ago   Up 17 minutes   0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp             e2i-scollado-cours-phpmyadmin
```

If I want to see Wordpress on my browser, I'm automatically redirect to PHPMyAdmin in this case.
But, even if I don't had a service on the port 8080, I'm still redirect to the port 8080.

Also, I've this problem with all of my docker-compose, here, it's just an example...

Please, if anyone have an answer, help me please ^^

Thank's

Comment: No idea how docker can affect this. Have you checked how the request goes with 'network' tab in browser developer tools? You should see there which address browser tries to access first and if there is a redirect response.

Comment: I just had a similar problem after playing with docker, wordpress and phpMyAdmin. In my case my browser had the redict in the cache and cleaning it fixed the problem.